# .Net Core application running on a linux container

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-container, docker-desktop, linux-containers

Following [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/build-container?tabs=windows) I build a `.Net Core` application and was able to run the application in a docker container. My host machine OS is Windows 10, and I now want to try to run the linked application in a Linux container. I have switched to Linux containers with Docker Desktop.

When I'm building the docker image I get this error:

```
failed to register layer: error creating overlay mount to /var/lib/docker/overlay2/f3e5279484774002c78a8eb66702c9ee7bca7038b59f4eeca7085b88dcbe25d9/merged: too many levels of symbolic links
```

The Dockerfile I've Used:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1-nanoserver-1903 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-nanoserver-1903 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["NetCore.Docker/NetCore.Docker.csproj", "NetCore.Docker/"]
RUN dotnet restore "NetCore.Docker/NetCore.Docker.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/NetCore.Docker"
RUN dotnet build "NetCore.Docker.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "NetCore.Docker.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "NetCore.Docker.dll"]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reason for this is I was using wrong image, had to change the image which support linux containers